# Purpose of removing the Firebase AuthStateListener for authentication on onPause() and adding it back on onResume()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following a three day coarse of firebase chat app on udemy here https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud0352

According to them, I've attached the authStateListener for authentication on the onCreate().

```
mAuthStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
        val user: FirebaseUser? = it.currentUser
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            onSignedInInitialized(user.displayName)
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            onSignedOutCleanup()
        }
    }
```

Later the suggested removing the state listener on the onPause function and attaching it back on the onStart function without proper explanation.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    if (mAuthStateListener !=null) {
        mFirebaseAuth!!.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener!!)
    }
    detachDatabaseReadListener()
    mMessageAdapter!!.clear()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mFirebaseAuth!!.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener!!)
}
```

I'm new to Android dev and Firebase and still cannot figure out the purpose of removing the adapter and listener on these functions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since your activity isn't at all visible to the user at onStop, it makes sense to stop things that might cause something to happen in your app that the user can't see.  Likewise, your activity is visible again during onStart, so you'd want to re-establish any behaviors that should be visible.

I suggest reading through the documentation for [Android lifecycle callbacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#lc) to better understand what they're used for.